# Callout accessory on tapping images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, callouts

I have some images in my viewcontroller's view. When I tap on each image I need to have a callout accessory, just like the one we get when we tap on a pin in the mapview. I read that this is normally used on annotations in mapviews. Could this be done on images in a view. Need help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own custom view similar to the annotation in mapview. That you can add on the  image on tap and remove that view when you tap again somewhere.